# Подскажите по оптимизации запросов

Tags: php, mysql

делаю полную выборку на 40 тыс. записей - памяти требует около 130 мб.

решил сделать выборку, разбив ее на части в цикле, т.е получилось 40 выборок по 1000 записей  - памяти занимает около 8 мб

Второй способ по памяти идеален, но в таком случае получается 40 запросов к базе.

Вопрос:  40 запросов за раз это нормально в данном случае ? (скрипт работает раз в час)

Comment: нормально, также можно после SELECT перечислять конкретные поля, исключив ненужные

Comment: А зачем выбирать 40 тыс записей ? пользователю вы их все вряд ли будете показывать. По крайней мере столько информации пользователь читать не станет. А вообще странно, неужели драйвера php всегда читают в память всю выборку. драйвера самой БД позволяют выполнить запрос, а потом читать в цикле записи, по мере необходимости, выбрасывая их из памяти как только стали не нужными

Answer (score 0):

Если убрать всякие мои лишние домыслы, которые породила окутавшая Ваш вопрос завеса тайны, то конкретный прямой ответ: да, раз в час 40 запросов это *в принципе* нормально. Нет понятия "хорошо" и "плохо" в разработке. Есть понятия "мне нужно", "мне в данном случае подходит", "дешевле будет стоить", "быстрее будет сделать" и т.д. в зависимости от ситуации. Никто не пишет идеальный код, все костылят время от времени. Если в данном случае второй вариант подходит, то так и делай.